# Access to localhost (10.0.2.2) Not Found

Tags: android, apache, android-emulator, localhost, wampserver

I saw a tutorial and It was fine until the guy did some wierd thing I couldn't find a way to do it to get my project running.
he could type 10.0.2.2 in the url bar of emulator and get to localhost page of wampserver
so I tried it but at first I had permission denied error and I fixed it, now when I type http://10.0.2.2 I get "Not Found The requested URL / was not found on this server". 
thanks for your help !
**UPDATE**: 
 Even when I try 127.0.0.1 in my computer it gives the same error 
 
PS : http://10.0.2.2 is not a private adress, it stands for localhost in android emulator. in fact it gives me wampserver error so it's accessing localhost, I just need to get rid of the error.
Thank you all !

Comment: That was probably his private IP address of his workstation.

Comment: his ?? stands for ?? and I did some research some basicaly 10.0.2.2 is the localhost adresse for android emulator

Comment: @YassineElhamraoui, I don't quite understand: 'his ?? stands for ??' You probably have some symbol instead of the question marks I'm unable to see?

Answer (score -2):

If you want localhost, write `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` into your webbrowser.

As [@vcsjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492405/vcsjones) pointed out in comments, the address you're talking about might be a private IP of his workstation.

Comment: no it's not that's what I said http://10.0.2.2 stands for localhost adress in android emulator I did the reseach. but even 127.0.0.1 gives me the same error "NOT FOUND"